# Access Array Elements - Out of PHP PDO

Tags: php, arrays, json, pdo

I have a JSON encoded array filled successfully as follows:

```
$profanityText = json_encode($pds->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

later I want to loop through this data and I do the following:

```
    $profanityTextArray = json_decode($profanityText);
    foreach ($profanityTextArray as $key => $jsons) {
      print_r($jsons);
    }
```

When I use the print_r($jsons) I get the following output:

```
stdClass Object
(
     [apple] => yes
     [peach] => yes2
     [banana] => no
)
(
     [apple] => yes
     [peach] => yes2
     [banana] => no
)
```

this is also fine. The catch is I don't know how to access individual elements during the foreach loop. eg: I want to be able to access apple and banana individual to make required decisions.

how can I access the elements individually rather then just print_r each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
foreach ($profanityTextArray as $key => $jsons) {
  echo $jsons->apple;
  echo $jsons->peach;
  echo $jsons->banana;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[A manual page **always** helps:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$profanityTextArray = json_decode($profanityText, TRUE);
foreach ($profanityTextArray as $row) {
    echo $row['apple'];
}
```

But what is the reason for encoding/decoding JSON? Can't you use fetchAll result already?

```
$profanityTextArray = $pds->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and then iterate this array usual way?

By the way, your question has nothing to do with PDO.
You have a regular array out of PDO, and it's source doesn't matter.